# json.serialize is corrupting datetime

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com

I am using json.serialize to pass a list into a visualforce page (in order to use it with a jquery library), for some reason the time of the date is 10 hours behind on the json 
I am wondering what do i need to do to avoid this?

this is a quick sample of how i build my list

```
    customBookingLst = new List<lstCalBookings>();
    string info1;
    string info2;
    datetime info3;
    datetime info4;
    List<Activity__c> list2 = [SELECT Name,Start__c,End__c FROM Activity__c WHERE (Start__c >= TODAY) ORDER BY Start__c ASC LIMIT 1000];
    for (Activity__c c:list2){
        info1 = c.Name;
        info2 = c.Name;
        info3 = c.Start__c;
        info4 = c.End__c;
        customBookingLst.add(new lstCalBookings(info1,info2,info3,info4));

    }
  test = json.serialize(customBookingLst);
```

wrapper class

```
public class lstCalBookings{
    public string id{get;set;}
    public string title{get;set;}
    public datetime start{get;set;}
    public datetime end1{get;set;}

    public lstCalBookings(string id,string title,datetime start,datetime i4){
            this.id = id;
            this.title = title;
            this.start = start;
            this.end1 = i4;
    }    
}  
Public List<lstCalBookings> customBookingLst{get;set;}
```

Comment: Is the timezone of the User logged in to generate the JSON 10 hours different from [UTC/GMT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)? JSON.serialize outputs the UTC value, which if you have users in different timezones is not a bad thing because then their client code can adjust to their local timezone (without having to first subtract out the timezone offset added by the server).

Comment: Thank you for the comment, well this VF page will be used in a different country to help creating bookings, so in this case it is really important to keep the real time, the one displayed in the field, otherwise the availability of the person will be different to the real one. So how can I adjust this ?

Comment: Keith also the problem is when I am doing the other way around, selecting datetime from VF page to Controller it is saved with 10h +, this is really bad as the salesforce users dont have accurate times